# Increment Y value of Vector3

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, vector

I am relearning 3D math with Unity right now and tinkering with the sample camera controller. By default it focuses on a target which in this case is the player, however I would like to add an offset to it, making it focus above the player's head.

```
namespace UnityStandardAssets._2D
{
    public class Camera2DFollow : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform target;
        public float damping = 1;
        public float lookAheadFactor = 3;
        public float lookAheadReturnSpeed = 0.5f;
        public float lookAheadMoveThreshold = 0.1f;

        private float m_OffsetZ;
        private Vector3 m_LastTargetPosition;
        private Vector3 m_CurrentVelocity;
        private Vector3 m_LookAheadPos;

        // Use this for initialization
        private void Start()
        {
            m_LastTargetPosition = target.position;
            m_OffsetZ = (transform.position - target.position).z;
            transform.parent = null;
        }


        // Update is called once per frame
        private void Update()
        {
            // only update lookahead pos if accelerating or changed direction
            float xMoveDelta = (target.position - m_LastTargetPosition).x;

            bool updateLookAheadTarget = Mathf.Abs(xMoveDelta) > lookAheadMoveThreshold;

            if (updateLookAheadTarget)
            {
                m_LookAheadPos = lookAheadFactor*Vector3.right*Mathf.Sign(xMoveDelta);
            }
            else
            {
                m_LookAheadPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(m_LookAheadPos, Vector3.zero, Time.deltaTime*lookAheadReturnSpeed);
            }

            Vector3 aheadTargetPos = target.position + m_LookAheadPos + Vector3.forward*m_OffsetZ;
            Vector3 newPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, aheadTargetPos, ref m_CurrentVelocity, damping);
            transform.position = newPos;

            m_LastTargetPosition = target.position;
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking I could simply add the following lines, however the camera flies off the screen vertically when doing so. What is wrong with this approach and how can I get this offset to actually work?

```
    Vector3 newPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, aheadTargetPos, ref m_CurrentVelocity, damping);
    Vector3 newPos2 = new Vector3(newPos.x, newPos.y + 1, newPos.z);
    transform.position = newPos2;
```

Comment: I would instead add a child GameObject to the player and set it to the desired position, and then use it as the camera target.

Comment: Done, thank you again!

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solve by adding a child GameObject to the player and set it to the desired position, and then use it as the camera target.

Also, doing this would make further changes in the position easier to carry out.

Answer (score 0):

You are using camera's position (i.e. transform.position) to calculate the camera's new position:

```
Vector3 newPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, aheadTargetPos, ref m_CurrentVelocity, damping);
```

then in the next two the lines you increase the new position's y and then reassign it to the camera transform position. So every frame camera's y position is increased causing it to "fly" away upwards.

You can in the `Start()` method set the camera's required y position and just not change it during your calculations

```
void Start() 
{
    Vector3 cameraPos = transform.position;
    cameraPos.y += 1;
    transform.position = cameraPos;
}
```

This will work as long as the Camera's y position is not changed in your calculations in the `Update()` method as it looks in your case

Comment: I tried adding that and tinkering with it some afterwards but was unable to get it to work. I did update the original post to include the full script though if that helps. Thank you for the response!

Comment: Just to note, as the script is attached to the camera, will "transform.position" return that of the "this" object (camera)?

Comment: Yes, if the script is attached to the camera game object then transform.position is the position of the camera